# Show that this function is infinitely often differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have the function $g(r):=e^{-\frac{1}{1-r}}$ for $r \in  [0,1)$ and $0$ for $r \ge 1$. Now, I want to show that $g \in C^{\infty}([0,\infty))$. I guess this can be shown somehow by finding an inductive pattern in the derivatives, but I don't see it.

Comment: You don’t need to find the exact pattern: it suffices to show by induction on $n$ that there are constants $c_{n,k}$ such that $$g^{(n)}(r)=g(r)\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{c_{n,k}}{(1-r)^k}$$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(r)$ be a rational function. Show that the derivative of $h(r)g(r)$ still is a rational function times $g(r)$.

Additionally, you need to show that the new rational function is well defined at any point where $h$ and $g$ was.

Comment: yeah, well this certainly depends on the kind of rational function don't you think? $\frac{1}{x}$ would not do it for example, as it has a singularity at $x=0$!

Comment: @XinWang You need to show that this process doesn't induce any _new_ singularities, apart from those already carried by $h$ and the exponent in $g$. Since the first step has $h(r) = 1$, you only get the $r = 1$ singularity from the exponent, no matter how many times you differentiate.